# PHP reading data input from a text file

Tags: php, input, output

I have a text file which I must read, and use the data from.

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

How can I create an array of these strings in the following form?

```
array(
    "name" => "number"
    ...
)
```

I tried this:

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
fscanf($handle, "%d %d", $name, $number);
```

What then? No matter what I try, it only works for the first line.

```
sam 99912222
```

Comment: What about the lines with no name/number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added codes to have both types of output - ignoring and including the lines that don't have name-value pairs. Check them out below

---

This code goes through each line and gets only the ones that have both `name` and `value` (`something[space]something)`):

```
//$lines = ... each line of the file in an array

$vals = array();
foreach($lines as $v){
    $tmp = explode(' ', $v);
    if(count($tmp) > 1){
        $vals[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]); // trim to prevent garbage
    }
}

print_r($vals);
```

It will output this:

```
Array
(
    [sam] => 99912222
    [tom] => 11122222
    [harry] => 12299933
)
```

See the code in action [here](https://eval.in/605953).

---

If you need the values even if they didn't come in pairs, do it like this:

```
//$lines = ... each line of the file

$vals = array();
foreach($lines as $v){
    $tmp = explode(' ', $v);
    $name = '';
    $number = '';
    $tmp[0] = trim($tmp[0]);
    if(count($tmp) > 1){
        $name = $tmp[0];
        $number = trim($tmp[1]);
    }else{
        if(is_numeric($tmp[0])){
            $number = $tmp[0];
        }else{
            $name = $tmp[0];
        }

    }
    $vals[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'number' => $number
    );
}

print_r($vals);
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [number] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => sam
            [number] => 99912222
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => tom
            [number] => 11122222
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => harry
            [number] => 12299933
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => sam
            [number] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => edward
            [number] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => harry
            [number] => 
        )
```

See the code in action [here](https://eval.in/605966).

Comment: You have my "up vote" both of you , because you spend your time trying to help me

Answer (score 1):

Data in file are inconsistent, best of is to use regex to identify what data you've got from each line.

```
$lines = file('file.txt'); // this will open file and split them into lines
$items = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
   $name = null;
   $number = null;
   $nameFound = preg_match("|([A-Za-z]+)|", $line, $matches);
   if($nameFound){
      $name = $matches[0];
   }
   $numberFound = preg_match("|([0-9]+)|", $line, $matches);
   if($numberFound){
      $number = $matches[0];
   }

   $items[] = array('name' => $name, 'number' => $number);
}
```

Then in items you should find parsed data from file.

To make it just extract full format data just change lines with regex into one line  like this:

```
$lines = file('file.txt'); // this will open file and split them into lines
$items = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
   $userFound = preg_match("/([A-Za-z]+) ([0-9]+)/", $line, $matches);
   if($userFound){
      $items[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
   }

}
```

Comment: I tested this and it didn't seem to work... [https://eval.in/605956](https://eval.in/605956) (Note that I'm not the op)

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in $matches try now

Comment: my input form to start in this problem is $_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");    I can't change it , that's it the single method how can I recieve data from that input

Comment: Take a look how it outputs ,

  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "sam"
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "sam"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "tom"
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "tom"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "harry"
    ["number"]=>
    string(5) "harry"
  }
  [4]=>


Without numbers

Comment: You have to first clear up what's the goal parse all or just extract lines with both values or what because based on that is just possible to help you.

Comment: You are perfectly right in the script above and It works for me to in that case when I declare the strings.
But what I have to deal with , is a problem on a coding website where I can't take out that information in that format .
Problem exactly is compresing data from $_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); 
. I have used fgets to take the data , also explode it to make it a array ,  but nothing works , only for the first name and number

Comment: You have my "up vote" both of you , because you spend your time trying to help me

Comment: Then use $fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
instead of foreach use while($line = fgets($fp)
and that's it

Comment: Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /run-OOyBA8HNwcN3UBubIFnW/solution.php on line 5

Comment: fopen was not working, but what you can do also is $stream = file_get_contents("php://stdin"); $lines = explode("\n", $stream);

Answer (score 1):

With the Algorithm below, you can simply parse each individual line of the Text-File Contents into an array with the 1st Word or Digit(s) on each line as the Key and the 2nd Word as the Value. When the 2nd word or group of words do not exist, a NULL is assigned to that Key. For re-usability, this algorithm has been encapsulated into a Function. Here you go:

```
<?php

    function parseTxtFile($txtFile){
        $arrTxtContent      = [];

        if(!file_exists($txtFile)){ return null;}
        $strFWriteTxtData   = file_get_contents($txtFile);

        if(empty($strFWriteTxtData)){return null;}

        $arrFWriteInfo      = explode("\n", $strFWriteTxtData);

        foreach($arrFWriteInfo as $iKey=>$lineData){
            $arrWriteData   = explode(", ", $lineData);
            foreach($arrWriteData as $intKey=>$strKeyInfo){
                preg_match("#(^[a-z0-9_A-Z]*)(\s)(.*$)#i", $strKeyInfo, $matches);
                preg_match("#(^[a-z0-9_A-Z]*)(\s*)?$#i", $strKeyInfo, $matches2);
                if($matches) {
                    list(, $key, $null, $val)   = $matches;
                    if (!array_key_exists($key, $arrTxtContent)) {
                        $arrTxtContent[$key]    = $val;
                    }else{
                        $iKey   = $intKey + 1;
                        $key    = $key . "_{$iKey}";
                        $arrTxtContent[$key]    = $val;
                    }
                }else if($matches2) {
                    list(, $key, $null)   = $matches2;
                    if (!array_key_exists($key, $arrTxtContent)) {
                        $arrTxtContent[$key]    = null;
                    }else{
                        $key = preg_match("#_\d+#", $key, $match)? $key . $match[0] : "{$key}_1";
                        $arrTxtContent[$key]    =  null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $arrTxtContent;
    }

    var_dump(parseTxtFile(__DIR__ . "/data.txt"));
```

Just call the function `parseTxtFile($txtFile)` passing it the path to your text File and it will return an Array that looks something like below:

```
    array (size=7)
      3         => null
      'sam'     => string '99912222' (length=8)
      'tom'     => string '11122222' (length=8)
      'harry'   => string '12299933' (length=8)
      'sam_1'   => null
      'edward'  => null
      'harry_1' => null
```

Hope this could help a bit....

Cheers & Good-Luck ;-)